# How to represent a grid or matrix of checkboxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, matrix, grid

I have the following entity, where `RowType` and `ColumnType` are enums:

```
public class MatrixEntry
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public RowType Row { get; set; }
    public ColumnType Column { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

I need to display this in a fixed N x N grid of `CheckBox`es (so the `Value` can be updated) and I'm struggling to find a good approach.

Is there a suitable control already available? Would it be easier to convert the data into a 2D array first? Should I write a converter, or just do something in the code behind?

I would also potentially like the enum display attribute for `RowType` and `ColumnType` displayed on the axis like so:

```
          Column1    Column2  Column3        
Row1         X                   X
Row2         X         X
Row3                             X
```

Comment: Use a UniformGrid as the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl. Assign or bind the ItemsSource property of the ItemsControl to a collection of MatrixEntry objects. Declare the CheckBox in the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl. Read [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: What are `RowType` and `ColumnType`? Are they relevant for display?

Comment: The enum description of `RowType` and `ColumnType` would be used on the axis

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using an [`ItemsControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), which is intended to display a collection of items. You can assign an [`ItemsPanelTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemspaneltemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to change the panel that is used to display the items. By default this is a stack panel that just stacks all items vertically. In your case a [`UniformGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) would be the best choice to get a matrix-like layout. The display of items can be defined using a [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), e.g. to show a `CheckBox`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MatrixEntries}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <UniformGrid Rows="3"
                      Columns="3"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MatrixEntry}">
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Please note, that I fixed the `Rows` and `Columns` so that I get a 3x3 matrix, but you are free to bind these properties dynamically instead of hard-coding them. This is just an example to build upon.

I defined a collection property for the matrix entries, it is exposed as an `IEnumerable<MatrixEntry>`, because I assume the matrix to be fixed in size.

```
public IEnumerable<MatrixEntry> MatrixEntries { get; }
```

I populate this collection with `MatrixEntry` instances. You can do this in code-behind, but ideally you would create a view model and follow the MVVM pattern to separate the view from your data and logic.

The `UniformGrid` will arrange the items in this collection automatically. If a row is full, it will populate the next row. If your items would contain row and column indices, you could alternatively use a [`Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) as items panel and bind its attached [`Grid.Row`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.row?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and [`Grid.Column`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.column?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) properties in the items template explicitly. However, this might be an advanced scenario.

One last remark about your data structure. If you intend to change the `Value` property from code and expect the `CheckBox` to update its state accordingly, you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, otherwise it is not notified about the change.

```
public class MatrixEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private bool _value;
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public RowType Row { get; set; }
   public ColumnType Column { get; set; }

   public bool Value
   {
      get => _value;
      set
      {
         if (value == _value)
            return;

         _value = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

This is what the result would look like for this example of a 3x3 matrix:

[image: A uniform grid of checkboxes.]

Resources for further reading:

- [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
- [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Thanks - this is useful, and you've answered my question well. However, I would also like the enum display attribute for `RowType` and `ColumnType` displayed on the axis, and potentially add an AlternationIndex. DataTemplating does seem like the best approach, but I'm not sure a UniformGrid is flexible enough for this?

Comment: @jimbo What do you mean by _displayed on the axis_? On which axis, where? The row and column type have individual values for each matrix entry? What do you want to achieve with the alternation index?

Comment: I mean: 

              Column1    Column2  Column3        
    Row1         X                                   X
    Row2         X                X
    Row3                                               X
 
With Column1/Row2/etc being the enum names.

Ignore the AlternationIndex comments.

Edit: And I've just realised I can't provide formatting in these comments.